# Google Anlytics event not firing

Tags: google-analytics

I am not getting and event data in GA.  I installed Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension and I see nothing happening (same goes when looking at Network panel in developer tools).  I Googled it and read many (many) other answers and it looks like I'm doing things right.  Page views, etc. *are* registering correctly...

I have this code as the last thing before my closing  tag:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-MYREALCODE', 'mybna.net');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-MYREALCODE']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

My event handlers are done using jQuery, all inside an external js file, loaded before the closing  tag.  For example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#show-less').click(function (e) {
        pbr.showHideMore(e);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ShowMore', 'Hide', 'top button']);
    });
});
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Just to make sure nothing obvious is missed, the two instances of UA-MYREALCODE point actually to different properties ?

Comment: Plus you do not seem to include ga.js. So _gaq is set but the functions you are pushing are not executed anywhere. Could you explain what you are doing (i.e. do you have two differen properties or are you trying to migrate a property to UA) ?

Comment: Thanks so much for the close attention you are paying to this.  UA-MYREALCODE is the same in both cases.  As I said in my comment to your answer below, things are working now (with the ga send syntax), however I have a nagging feeling that I am missing an important point you're trying to make....

Comment: The difference is between the "classic" asynchronous syntax using the _gaq array and the new Universal Analytics. A property is configured for either of them, never for both. You can have an UA tracker and an asynchronous tracker on the same page, but they need to track to different properties (which might or might not be in the same account), and their methods are not interchangable (if you are using UA exclusively  you can remove all references to __gaq from your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I keep deleting and undeleting this anwswer because I'm not sure if your code is redundant or if you are actually trying to send data to two different properties.

If it's the first, see original answer below. For the latter make sure that you account/property-Ids are pointing to correctly configured properties (i.e. the first UA, the latter asynchronous), plus I'm pretty sure you need to include the ga.js liberary two if you want the methods pushed in the array to be executed.

You are mixing Universal Analytics and asynchronous code, that's not going to work (i.e. if you have ga send and _gaq.push in the same piece of code you are most probably doing it wrong). Adapt your [event tracking code for UA](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) and you should be alright.

Comment: Thanks Eike.  Using the object syntax did the job:
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'some-category',
  eventAction: 'some-action',
  eventLabel': 'some-label'
});  I thought documentation said this and push syntax are interchangeable...  I think added benefit of this syntax is that other than required keys you can send whatever additional keys you make up.  Do you know by chance how long its supposed to take until I see the events in GA interface ?

Comment: @yar1 usually within 4 hours (or immediately in the real time view), but with large accounts (Google specifies large as more than 200 000 interactions per day) it'll take up to 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the click listener in a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show-less').click(function (e) {
        pbr.showHideMore(e);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ShowMore', 'Hide', 'top button']);
    });
});
```

I often find that the listener won't link up until the DOM is fully loaded.  Sometimes it does, though, but that might have to do with the code being below the object in question in the code.

It always helps me to put an "alert" into the click function while testing to be sure it's actually firing off (and catching) that event.

Comment: That's what $(function () { does

Comment: Well I'll be...  what about scope?  Do you think _gaq is out of scope in that context?

Comment: You say the Analytics code is the *last* thing before your closing tag, but then you say you are including your externals last.  Are you including  your externals *after* the Analytics invocation block?

Comment: SeanKendle: _gaq is in global scope and available at time of call (I tested using debug tool); Analytics code is last in <head>, my code is last in <body>